# How can I call Windows Virtual Desktop Cmdlets for PowerShell from a serverless environment?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-powershell

Is there any way to invoke the PowerShell APIs for Windows Virtual Desktop in a serverless or event driven way?

Specifically, I would like to automate a call to `Add-RdsAppGroupUser` or `Remove-RdsAppGroupUser` based on some external event.

How could I do that? Are Azure Cloud Functions suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Azure Automation runbook. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/automation/
This is a service designed for this.

Comment: I don't see Windows Virtual Desktop Cmdlets as an option in the Runbooks. Can I call Add-RdsAppGroupUser or Remove-RdsAppGroupUser?

Comment: I've tried this approach and I get the error "The term 'Add-RdsAppGroupUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" Is there a way to import or reference additional cmdlets?

Comment: This is the correct answer, as PowerShell Core is not supported at this point in time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this certainly is possible.  A PowerShell Function is probably most suitable to this kind of task, but you could use any of the function runtimes.

PS functions are relatively new so documentation is not yet as full as for other runtimes.  However, the same concepts apply.

For authentication you should create a service principal.  You can use the CLI or PowerShell.  Instructions on using PowerShell here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-2.8.0

Once created you'll need to assign it the necessary permissions to your host pool/cluster and use the `Login-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal` parameter set with the credentials generated.

As for the function being triggered by events, of course you have the choice of Event Grid, Event Hub, or Service Bus.  If the function executions per month are quite low (less than 10000) it's probably best to elect a consumption-based function with Azure Event Grid.

Comment: Part of my confusion is the documentation for Windows Virtual Desktop Cmdlets, it indicates it will not run where PS Core is supported

Comment: Part of my confusion is the documentation for Windows Virtual Desktop Cmdlets, it indicates it will not run where PS Core is supported, and the Azure Functions runtime seems to be PS Core. I am new to Azure so I'll try following your steps and see if the Cmdlets run.                                                                              https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows-virtual-desktop/overview